# Regexp - find a value between a part of the string and a second part of the string OR end of line

Tags: python, regex

I've looked through many regexp examples here, but still fail to find a solution.

I have to check a request string for a certain substring in it. The substring in question will have something before it might have something after:

`?something=xxx&to_dep=YYY&from_dep=zzz&...`
OR
`?something=xxx&to_dep=YYY`

I need to extract YYY without a `&` in first case and simply YYY in the second case.

For now I use this kind of regexp:

`re.search('to_dep=(.+?)&', req.query_string)`

but works only in one case and can't be used if I want to re.sub it. (replace YYY with something else - `&` gets replaced too)

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both, you might use a positive lookbehind and a negated class:

```
re.search(r'(?<=to_dep=)[^&]+', req.query_string)
```

And this will give you only `YYY`, which then means you can also use it in `re.sub`:

```
re.sub(r'(?<=to_dep=)[^&]+', 'new_value', req.query_string)
```

`[^&]` matches any character except `&`.

`(?<=to_dep=)` makes sure there's a `to_dep=` before the part to match.

Answer (score 2):

Just try with:

```
[?&]to_dep=([^&]*)
```

`[^&]*` will match any characters that are not `&` or it will stop on the next `&` (first case) or stop on the end of the string (second case).